# update item in array according to existing value

Tags: mongoose

This is my schema, and i'm trying to do the following:

```
const myModel = new Schema({
    dummy: String,
    users: [{
        created: Date,
        emails: { type: Number, default: 0 }
    }]
})
```

I'm trying to figure out how to increment the `emails` field by a certain value. the `emails` field is part of`users` array.

When I run the following query then the amount of emails for my certain user is set to 123

```
myModel.findOneAndUpdate(query , {$set: {'users.$.emails': 123}},  function (err, userDoc){
```

But what i'm looking for is to increment the number of `emails` by an input number `numberOfEmails`

```
myModel.findOneAndUpdate(query , {$set: {$inc: 'users.$.emails': numberOfEmails}},  function (err, userDoc){
```

But the number of `emails` is not incremented.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your schema code please

Comment: @Asish i've added schema to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to increment the `emails` with certain value

```
myModel.findOneAndUpdate(query , {$inc: {'users.$.emails': 123}},  function (err, userDoc){
```